# org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException when running test cases of Kafka Java project

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

```
2017-09-06 11:58:16.380  WARN 8376 --- [ry:/127.0.0.1:0] o.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn  : caught end of stream exception

org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x15e55dfd1a70001, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) ~[zookeeper-3.4.9.jar:3.4.9-1757313]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:203) [zookeeper-3.4.9.jar:3.4.9-1757313]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112]

2017-09-06 11:58:16.381  INFO 8376 --- [ry:/127.0.0.1:0] o.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn  : Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:53191 which had sessionid 0x15e55dfd1a70001
2017-09-06 11:58:16.427  INFO 8376 --- [127.0.0.1:53184] org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread        : Terminate ZkClient event thread.
2017-09-06 11:58:16.428  INFO 8376 --- [0 cport:53184):] o.a.z.server.PrepRequestProcessor        : Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x15e55dfd1a70000
2017-09-06 11:58:16.494  INFO 8376 --- [           main] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper           : Session: 0x15e55dfd1a70000 closed
2017-09-06 11:58:16.496  INFO 8376 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     : shutting down
2017-09-06 11:58:16.497 ERROR 8376 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     : ZKShutdownHandler is not registered, so ZooKeeper server won't take any action on ERROR or SHUTDOWN server state changes
2017-09-06 11:58:16.497  INFO 8376 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.SessionTrackerImpl  : Shutting down
2017-09-06 11:58:16.497  INFO 8376 --- [           main] o.a.z.server.PrepRequestProcessor        : Shutting down
2017-09-06 11:58:16.497  INFO 8376 --- [           main] o.a.z.server.SyncRequestProcessor        : Shutting down
2017-09-06 11:58:16.494  INFO 8376 --- [ain-EventThread] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : EventThread shut down for session: 0x15e55dfd1a70000
2017-09-06 11:58:16.495  WARN 8376 --- [ry:/127.0.0.1:0] o.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn  : caught end of stream exception

org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x15e55dfd1a70000, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) ~[zookeeper-3.4.9.jar:3.4.9-1757313]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:203) [zookeeper-3.4.9.jar:3.4.9-1757313]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112]

2017-09-06 11:58:16.498  INFO 8376 --- [ry:/127.0.0.1:0] o.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn  : Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:53187 which had sessionid 0x15e55dfd1a70000
2017-09-06 11:58:16.499  INFO 8376 --- [0 cport:53184):] o.a.z.server.PrepRequestProcessor        : PrepRequestProcessor exited loop!
2017-09-06 11:58:16.499  INFO 8376 --- [   SyncThread:0] o.a.z.server.SyncRequestProcessor        : SyncRequestProcessor exited!
2017-09-06 11:58:16.500  INFO 8376 --- [           main] o.a.z.server.FinalRequestProcessor       : shutdown of request processor complete
2017-09-06 11:58:16.501  INFO 8376 --- [ry:/127.0.0.1:0] o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory        : NIOServerCnxn factory exited run method
2017-09-06 11:58:16.506  INFO 8376 --- [ SessionTracker] o.a.zookeeper.server.SessionTrackerImpl  : SessionTrackerImpl exited loop!
2017-09-06 11:58:17.542  INFO 8376 --- [       Thread-9] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2de366bb: startup date [Wed Sep 06 11:58:09 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-09-06 11:58:17.560  INFO 8376 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
2017-09-06 11:58:17.560  INFO 8376 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
```

I have looked through these links where a similar exception is discussed:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1582
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4793

I have tried using `jute.maxbuffer=50000000` in zookeeper.properties file as I'm using Kafka-setup-packaged-zookeeper. This solution was mentioned in the above JIRA tickets. But the exception still occurred.

Any suggestions what could be the possible solution, in my case?

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I meet the similar exception.

Comment: I have same exception.

Comment: One of my junior colleagues solved this issue, but she couldn't send the exact solution. So, I don't have a solution yet.